# Adding dynamically TextView to ScrollView on Android

Tags: android, dynamic, textview, scrollview

I try to make a ScrollView to act like a ListView.
Every row will be a TextView added dynamically.
So i try this code

```
this.scrollView = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollView1);
this.linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout2);
this.linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
TextView[] tx = new TextView[10];
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    tx[i] = new TextView(this);
    tx[i].setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
tx[i].setText("This is the textviewNo" + i);
this.linearLayout.addView(tx[i]);
}
this.scrollView.addView(this.linearLayout);
setContentView(this.scrollView);
```

But i get this exception

```
10-28 13:35:59.120: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2346): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ScrollView can host only one direct child
```

at the line this.scrollView.addView(this.linearLayout)
What i do wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Exception is pretty clear: you can not add more than one child to ScrollView. From you code I assume that `linearLayout2` is already inside ScrollView? If so, than you do not need

```
this.scrollView.addView(this.linearLayout);
```

at all, since you add TextViews to LinearLayout which is already inside the ScrollView